# Is it possible to use Http digest auth with Uptime?

Tags: node.js, uptime-monitoring

Is it possible to use http digest authentication with the [Uptime tool](https://github.com/fzaninotto/uptime)? It uses Node.js' HTTPS library and says to use documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) to read more about parameters. I don't see a way to specify digest authentication in the node.js https documentation (linked). Can anyone with more node.js chops point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cleanest way, but you could implement a custom poller, using a library that supports digest, as I don't think the default http library used by the http/https pollers support digest out of the box.

The [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) package seems to support digest authentication. Here ( https://gist.github.com/macadada/aafaca2665347945ff66 ) is a sample poller that I based off the https poller and changed to use the [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) library so that it does digest authentication.